# Do Facebook app restrictions affect sign in from within an app?

Tags: facebook

I want to soft launch a mobile app which has Facebook sign in integrated using the Facebook Unity SDK. I understand that I can use the Allowed Countries app restriction to do this.

Does the restriction stop people in other countries signing in within my app, or just stop it showing up on the Facebook website/app? I want the app to be publicly available in New Zealand only, but I also want to invite testers and journalists from other countries to try out the game.

Comment: I’m pretty sure it will stop people in other countries from using the app too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I confirmed that the setting does stop users from outside the Allowed Countries from signing in.

After I soft launched my game in New Zealand, I revoked one of my friend's tester role. He was no longer able to sign in (being in the UK). Users outside of the Allowed Countries will not be able to sign in without being added as a tester.